# Can I move CKRecords from one CKContainer to another?

Tags: ios, cloudkit, ckrecord

I had to change my Apple ID, but I have numerous important records in the production environment in a container of my old Apple ID.

Can I export them while maintaining the dependencies and record authors?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer: No
But you could manually copy over records from one container to the other (or first create an export and then create an import). But then It will look like new data in the new container an it will also have new metadata. So the creator will be the account used to migrated the data. And you would need an app (OS X or iOS) that can connect to the production public container.

Comment: I also first came to this decision, but if we transfer the application from one account to another that will be with container? According to my logic container must also transfer.

Comment: CloudKit containers are linked to a developer account. You can have multiple apps connecting to the same container. These apps must be signed using the same developer account.

Comment: Thank, looks rationally.